# Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a bug and I have no idea why? I wrote a login using Spring Boot Spring Security + JWT. But I have a weird repository bug.

I have been trying to do this for several hours but I don't have the strength for it anymore. I don't know it matters but I use as a base PostgreSQL

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.tiscode.xxxxx_api.repository.UserRepository.findByName(java.lang.String)! No property name found for type User!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1828) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:2.3.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
at
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByName(String user);
```

My UserDetalsServiceImp

```
   @Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByName(userName)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User Not Found with username: " + userName));

        return UserDetailsImpl.build(user);
    }

}
```

And my Entity User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable( name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

    public User(String username, String email, String password) {
        this.userName = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User() {
    }

....
```

Comment: Is there a User entity lying somewhere in your classpath ?

Comment: Can you show your User entity? It seems you have no field called 'name'.

Comment: 36ve @JeannotMn  I just added User Entity

Comment: You  call your column 'name 'instead of 'userName'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes on the `User` object is called `userName`, not `name`.

That's why Spring is complaining "No property name found for type User!".

Try the following:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findByUserName(String user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please rename method and parameter. Should be:

```
Optional<User> findByUserName(String userName);
```

And please remove "@Repository" annotation